# Select 2 Drop Downs simultaneously using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a python script using selenium that should select a value in the drop down. It worked perfect!
Now I am trying to select two drop downs and both the drop downs have same class_name. I have managed to write the script but its throwing error.

```
    driver.get("url")

    select = Select(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rs_select"))
    print select

    for nos in len(select):
        for i in nos:
            x = [o.text for o in i.options]                
            i.select_by_visible_text(str(len(x)-1))

    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("continue")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I am trying to select the maximum value available (it will be the last value) from the drop downs.
I dont know if my code is correct, please help. This is the error I m getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
select = Select(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rs_select"))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 35, in __init__
if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

Comment: where do you get element by attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. You want to get all the `SELECT`s in a `list` and iterate through them. For each `SELECT`, use `select_by_index` to choose the last option by index instead of the visible text.

```
driver.get("url")

selects = Select(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rs_select"))
print selects

for select in selects:
    select.select_by_index(len(selects.options))
    // you may need a slight pause here to let the select magic happen

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("continue")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for but I am getting an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'